# HttpClient and HttpGet Support in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am building an app which is already build in Android & other Mobile Platform. Since the App uses REST based Webservices build in JAVA, thus I need to use these Webservice URL. The code uses HttpClient and HttpGet for GET,POST,PUT & DELETE operation in Android . Can anyone guide me where to start with as I am new to this Platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the WebClient class for simple HTTP based communication. Here is the basic format I typically use when making a request to a web service:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(RequestComplete);
web.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("http://fullurlofyourwebservice.com"));
```

You can then write a method for the RequestComplete method referenced in the second line of code:

```
void RequestComplete(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string response = "";

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(e.Result))
            {
                response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
```

You can then process the response as a  simple string, or do something like `XDocument.Parse(response)` if your response is in XML format.

Check out the full [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for a complete reference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. It worked for me ... How can I perform POST operation if I need to post a JSON string using WebClient. A sample Code would help me better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use HttpWebRequest ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.95).aspx ) to make calls to a REST service

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using RestSharp. http://restsharp.org/

Small, simple and does what it says on the box.